# When a method uses a cache, but occasionally does I/O, should it return T, or Task<T>?

Tags: c#, task

So my question basically comes down to, should I return a Task, so the caller can be async, even if 99% of the time, there is no I/O?

Say my code is something like:

```
var countryList = _cacheService.Get<List<Country>>("Countries", LoadCountrys);
```

In this example, **LoadCountrys** is a method that will make the I/O call.
So the first time this is called, it will do some I/O to load all the countries into a cache, then each call after that will just read from an in-memory cache (no I/O).

The method signature would look like:

```
List<Country> GetCountryList();
```

The other way to do this would be:

```
var countryList = await _cacheService.GetAsync<List<Country>>("Countries", LoadCountrysAsync);
```

The method signature would look like:

```
List<Country> GetCountryListAsync();
```

It seems wasteful to me, paying for the overhead of a Task, when most of the time the code is not truly async.

However in [Joe Duffy's blog](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/#variable-latency-and-asynchrony), in the section **Variable latency and asynchrony**, he goes on to say even if you rarely do I/O, you should still return a Task.

So are my gut instincts wrong? Or maybe the Task overhead is so small it doesn't matter? Or is this a "It depends" kind of answer?

Comment: So basically your question "is it ok to freeze UI for 5 minutes from time to time" - answer should be clear: it is indeed perfectly fine because it makes function signature cleaner... :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I get your sarcasm, but the code might not be consumed by a desktop UI. For example it might be part of a server-side web request.

Comment: You need to come up with good use case that justifies synchronous wait for long time - potentially minutes (and no, web-server code is just as vulnerable to that as UI - small number of properly crafted requests will eat all available threads with even more entertaining results than desktop app).

Comment: @DavidG OP is looking for opinions on whether `_cacheService.Get..` or `_cacheService.GetAsync...` is universally better (I expressed mine in comments, but I'm not sure if this is just opinion based question).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Grr, I should have gone to bed instead of mooching around SO! :)

Comment: There is little to no overhead in awaiting a completed task. It will be equivalent of one property check (IsCompleted == true) and then just executing the continuation synchronously.

Comment: Cache the completed `Task`.

Comment: @user1909158: The question is not "how often is it async", but rather "can it ever be async". If yes, then `Task<T>` is the correct return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to handle this is return a `Task<T>`, however you don't need to make your "fast path" async and incur the overhad. Just use `Task.FromResult` or call a 2nd async to actually execute the factory method to get the value.

```
public static class CacheManager
{
    public static Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> factory)
where T : class
    {
        var result = (T)MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }

        return RunFactory<T>(cacheKey, factory);
    }

    private static async Task<T> RunFactory<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> factory)
        where T : class
    {
        await PurgeOldLocks();
        var cacheLock = _locks.GetOrAdd(cacheKey, (key) => new SemaphoreSlim(1));
        try
        {
            //Wait for anyone currently running the factory.
            await cacheLock.WaitAsync();

            //Check to see if another factory has already ran while we waited.
            var oldResult = (T)MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey);
            if (oldResult != null)
            {
                return oldResult;
            }

            //Run the factory then cache the result.
            var newResult = await factory();
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, newResult, _myDefaultPolicy);
            return newResult;
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.Release();
        }
    }

    private static async Task PurgeOldLocks()
    {
        try
        {
            //Only one thread can run the purge;
            await _purgeLock.WaitAsync();
            if ((DateTime.UtcNow - _lastPurge).Duration() > MinPurgeFrequency)
            {
                _lastPurge = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var locksSnapshot = _locks.ToList();
                foreach (var kvp in locksSnapshot)
                {
                    //Try to take the lock but do not wait for it.
                    var waited = await kvp.Value.WaitAsync(0);
                    if (waited)
                    {
                        //We where able to take the lock so remove it from the collection and dispose it.
                        SemaphoreSlim _;
                        _locks.TryRemove(kvp.Key, out _);
                        kvp.Value.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _purgeLock.Release();
        }
    }

    public static TimeSpan MinPurgeFrequency { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    private static DateTime _lastPurge = DateTime.MinValue;

    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _purgeLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();

    private static CacheItemPolicy _myDefaultPolicy = //...
}
```

In order to make sure two threads don't run a factory at the same time I keep a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>` to lock running of the factory. However this will lead to memory leaks so once a hour I go through the list in a exclusive lock and delete any key I can take the lock on.

Answer (score 1):

> should I return a Task, so the caller can be async, even if 99% of the
>   time, there is no I/O?

My answer is YES. Theoretically speaking, `async` methods are probably slightly slower, because more codes are generated/executed (the state machine). But the spot is negligible because `async` [brings more](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8XXnVqbIIvTC8gfxzIEg&gws_rd=cr,ssl#q=async+method+benefit).

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "async brings more"?

Comment: @user1909158 You can search `async method benefit`, lots of articles give the answer. I've added the link into the answer.